# Logstash Error - how to trace

Tags: ruby, logstash

I'm getting the following in my Logstash log, and can't figure out where it's coming from:

> > {:timestamp=>"2016-05-19T12:14:00.883000-0400", :message=>"Ruby exception occurred: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass", :level=>:error}

I have some other errors, too and I can't tell which record is causing it.  I suspect my error here is from the date manipulation, but the question is more general.

How can I make logstash print the entire event that causes this error, or any similar one?

My filter an output look like this, the input is from a JDBC source:

```
filter {
  mutate
  {
    convert => [ "dt", "string" ]
  }
  date {
    match => [ "dt", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"]
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event['idx'] = event['dt'][0..9]"
  }
  ruby {
    code => "event['id'] = event['@timestamp'].time().to_f.to_s + '' + event['sessionid']"
  }

}

output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost" ]
    index => "prefix-%{idx}"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to run with `--debug` option?

Comment: Yes, and it outputs so much info it's useless.  Is there a way to print *only the whole error record*?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this line is in `filter` method of `ruby` filter:

```
def filter(event)
  begin
    @codeblock.call(event)
    filter_matched(event)
  rescue Exception => e
    @logger.error("Ruby exception occurred: #{e}")
    event.tag("_rubyexception")
  end
end
```

I think you can add a error message to print the `event`. So you will know which event cause the error:

```
def filter(event)
  begin
    @codeblock.call(event)
    filter_matched(event)
  rescue Exception => e
    @logger.error("Ruby exception occurred: #{e}")
    @logger.error("Event causing error: #{event}") # <= Log event
    event.tag("_rubyexception")
  end
end
```

It is in file: vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-filter-ruby-2.0.5/lib/logstash/filters/ruby.rb for Logstash 2.3.2

Comment: were you able find a more general way to log on every error like a plugin or any file change?